# Getting "error WINHTTP in `ie_get_proxy_for_url` "

Tags: r, windows, download

Here is an error I get on Windows:

```r
> usethis::use_news_md()
✔ Setting active project to 'C:/SL/MyPackages/giacR'
Error in ie_get_proxy_for_url(test_url) : 
  ERROR_WINHTTP_UNABLE_TO_DOWNLOAD_SCRIPT
```

And I get a similar error when I try to install **RcppCGAL** from Github. This package performs a download at the installation.

What does this error mean and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Is it the same for `curl::has_internet()` ? Kind of guess, but it seems to lead to Windows proxy configuration that might be managed by your organisation. Are you moving between networks? Does this happen mostly/only when you are using a network outside of your organisation, or only with / without VPN or something?

Comment: @margusl Indeed, this is the laptop from my job.

Comment: If you open Windows proxy settings and happen to have "use setup script" enabled, you can check if you have access to that script from your current network.

Comment: And indeed, `curl::has_internet()` generates exactly the same error.